# Betti numbers of resolutions of homeomorphic singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $K/\mathbb{C}$ and $L/\mathbb{C}$ be finitely generated field extensions.

Assume there are singular projective varieties that have $K$ and $L$ as their function fields and whose complex points are homeomorphic.

Are there non-singular projective varieties that have $K$ and $L$ as their function fields and whose complex points have equal Betti numbers?

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, yes in dimension two. Resolve the singularities of both any way you like. Since topological fundamental group is a birational invariant and a homeomorphism invariant, both have the same $b_{1}=b_{3}$. Now blowing up smooth points we can arrange for them to have the same $b_{2}$.